# How to find the lowest value in a hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am unable to find the lowest value in a hashmap. There is only one hashmap and in it the lowest value of players must be found.

```java
                for (Map.Entry<Player, Integer> entry1 : lowestTrump.entrySet()) {
                    Player key1 = entry1.getKey();
                    int value1 = entry1.getValue();

                    for (Map.Entry<Player, Integer> entry2 : lowestTrump.entrySet()) {
                        Player key2 = entry2.getKey();
                        int value2 = entry2.getValue();

                        if(value1 == -1 || value2 == -1){
                            break;
                        }else if(value1 < value2 && (value1 != 1 || value2 != 1)) {
                            attackerFound = key1.getName();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The output should assign the lowest value among Players into attackerFound variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the minimum player in a single step like this:

```
Player lowestPlayer = lowestTrump.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .orElse(null);

String attackerFound = lowestPlayer != null ? lowestPlayer.getName() : null;
```

Be aware that if `lowestTrump` was empty then `attackerFound` will be `null`.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I made a tiny change

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a `stream()` with `min()` to get the lowest value

```
lowestTrump.values().stream().min(Integer::compareTo);
```

---

if the `lowestTrump` can be null you can also wrap `lowestTrump.values()` with apache `CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull())` or use some another null-safe approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use treemap. So that when you add any value to that map, It will already be sorted. You can get first value and that will be the lowest or wise Versa.

```
Map <Player, Integer> playerMap = new TreeMap<Player, Integer>();
```

For Java 8+ you can use below example :

```
playerMap.values().stream().min(Integer::compareTo);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my actual working code

```
                Optional<Player> result = lowestTrump.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(c -> c.getValue() != -1)
                        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
                        .map(Map.Entry::getKey);

                if(result != null && result.get().getSuitInHand() != -1) {
                    System.out.println("Player : " + result.get().getName() + " is the first attacker");
                }
```